# Nested list to show product options

Tags: expresso-store, stash

In the following code I'm using Expresso store to stash the current user's basket away.

Win it I'm setting a nested list so that I can loop through the options and display them as a definition list.

However that nested list doesn't seem to be returning.

Can anybody spot what's wrong here?

**Set List**

```
{exp:store:cart}
    {exp:stash:set name="basket-total"}{order_subtotal}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="basket-items" process_tags="yes"}
        {items}
            {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
            {stash:quantity}{item_qty}{/stash:quantity}
            {stash:entry-id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry-id}
            {stash:price}{exp:stash:embed:rcf:ecom_price stash:entry-id="{entry_id}"}{/stash:price}
            {stash:subtotal}{item_subtotal}{/stash:subtotal}

            {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="options"}
                {modifiers}
                    {stash:option}{modifier_name}{/stash:option}
                    {stash:value}{modifier_value}{/stash:value}
                {/modifiers}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}
        {/items}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:store:cart}
```

---

**Get List**

```
    {exp:stash:get_list name="basket-items"}
        <tr>
            <td class="basket--image"><img src="http://placehold.it/90x90"></td>
            <td class="basket--item">
                <strong>{title}</strong>
                <ul class="basket--item--controls">
                    <li><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="basket--options">
                <dl>
                    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="options"}
                        <dt>{option}</dt>
                        <dd>{value}</dd>
                    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                    <dt>Quantity:</dt>
                    <dd>{quantity}</dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="basket--item-sub-total">{subtotal}</td>
        </tr>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using `process_tags` instead of the correct `parse_tags`.

For people who found this, this is the code that works so far.

**Setter**

```
{exp:store:cart}
{exp:stash:set name="basket-total"}{order_subtotal}{/exp:stash:set}

{!-- Set a list of all the products in the user's basket and save it for 2 hours unless the user updates it --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="basket-items" scope="user" save="yes" refresh="120" {if segment_2=="added"||segment_2=="updated"}replace="yes"{/if} parse_tags="yes"}
    {items}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:quantity}{item_qty}{/stash:quantity}
        {stash:entry-id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry-id}
        {stash:price}{exp:stash:embed:rcf:ecom_price stash:entry-id="{entry_id}"}{/stash:price}
        {stash:subtotal}{item_subtotal}{/stash:subtotal}
        {stash:key}{key}{/stash:key}

        {!-- Stash the modifiers for this option away --}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested name="options-{key}"}
            {modifiers}
                {stash:option}{modifier_name}{/stash:option}
                {stash:value}{modifier_value}{/stash:value}
            {/modifiers}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

    {/items}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:store:cart}
```

**Getter**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">In stock available to buy today</th>
        <th>Your Options</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Subtotal</td>
        <td>{stash:basket-total}</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="basket-items"}
        <tr>
            <td class="basket--image"><img src="http://placehold.it/90x90"></td>
            <td class="basket--item">
                <strong>{title} - {key}</strong>
                <ul class="basket--item--controls">
                    <li><a href="#">Remove</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="basket--options">
                <dl>
                    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="options-{key}" parse="inward"}
                        <dt>{option}</dt>
                        <dd>{value}</dd>
                    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
                    <dt>Quantity:</dt>
                    <dd>{quantity}</dd>
                </dl>
            </td>
            <td class="basket--item-sub-total">{subtotal}</td>
        </tr>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
</tbody>
```